# не могу поставить точку останова на полях редактора vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

не могу поставить точку останова в редакторе vscode. Именно красный кружочек слева на полях, вместо этого появляется всплывающее окно Добавить Breakpoint.. Никак не ставится даже через меню